# OpenGL framebuffer rendering fails at high resolution

Tags: c++, opengl, framebuffer

In my code, I'm rendering the Mandelbrot fractal and I noticed that when I up the resolution from 7680x4320 to 15360x8640 the output image becomes blank with no OpenGL errors reported.

The dimensions are within the allowed 16384x16384 limit and the GPU memory is not being overflowed because I get no Out-of-memory Errors.

- My GPU: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000, Build 10.18.10.4425
- OpenGL Version: 4.0.0

Code:

```
constexpr GLsizei Width  = 15360;
constexpr GLsizei Height = 8640;

// Note: I'm only using GLFW for the OpenGL context
glfwInit();
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VISIBLE, GL_FALSE);
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "Mandelbrot Generator", nullptr, nullptr); // the resolution of the window is not important
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

// Note: I'm wrapping OpenGL calls to allow for glGetError() to be called for each func
// Code to generate framebuffer
gl::GenFramebuffers(1, &fbo);
gl::GenRenderbuffers(1, &rbo);
gl::BindRenderBuffer(rbo);
gl::SetRenderbufferStorage(gl::e_RGBA, Width, Height);
gl::BindFramebuffer(gl::e_DrawFramebuffer, fbo);
gl::SetFramebufferRenderBuffer(gl::e_DrawFramebuffer, gl::e_ColorAttachment0, rbo);

// Rendering
gl::BindFramebuffer(gl::e_DrawFramebuffer, fbo);
{
    gl::Clear(gl::e_ColorBufferBit);
    gl::SetViewport(0, 0, Width, Height);
    gl::BindBuffer(gl::e_ArrayBuffer, rect); // rect is a fullscreen quad
    gl::DrawArrays(gl::e_Triangles, 0, 6);
    gl::BindBuffer(gl::e_ArrayBuffer, 0);
}
gl::BindFramebuffer(gl::e_DrawFramebuffer, 0);

// Saving image
std::vector<GLubyte> pixels(Width * Height * 4);
{
    gl::BindFramebuffer(gl::e_ReadFramebuffer, fbo);
    gl::ReadPixels(0, 0, Width, Height, gl::e_RGBA, gl::e_UnsignedByte, pixels.data());
}
lodepng::encode("mandelbrot.png", pixels, Width, Height);
```

Comment: What makes you so sure 16384 is the actual limit for your particular GPU/driver combination?

Comment: @derhass I queried OpenGL with GL_MAX_RENDERBUFFER_SIZE

Comment: Do you have the documentation of SavePNG(..) ?

Comment: @HannesHauptmann I didn't want to complicate the code but, I use lodepng to save and load (Check the edited code).

Comment: Sorry about that. According to a [more recent driver](http://opengl.gpuinfo.org/gl_generatereport.php?reportID=1813), the limitation was increased to 16K. So this is probably a case of Intel being Intel.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes, I should specify my driver version as that is what I have.